# waiting for users response

Tags: c#

when form is loaded `myMethod()` is called and then it executes some statements. at some point when it gets to if statement it should stop and wait for user to press some button and then it will continue executing according to what user did. i used `Thread.Sleep()` and ManualResetEvent obj's `WaitOne()` method but they seem to freeze the whole process nothing can be done until the time expires. I think that KeyEventHandler in should be run in background so it never feezzed... Anyway how can I do that ?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool pressed = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
        {
            pressed = true;
        }
    }

    void myMethod()
    { 
        while (someBool)
        {
            //do something
            if (pressed)
            //do this
            else 
            //do that
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to run `myMethod()` on a separate thread, or maybe you want to rethink your design. Why not just put the relevant part of the `myMethod()` in the key press event handler?

Comment: if i put the part of myMethod() in key press event handler user need time to press the key right ? but while myMethod is executed program cannot catch pressed keys unless its executed on different thread

Comment: Put the first part of `myMethod` (`//do something`) into `Form_Load`, put the second part (`//do this`) in the `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)`, put the third part (`//do that`) into `else`.

Comment: that would work in this case but i forgot to write that myMthod() has loop inside of it and everything is executed in that while loop.

Comment: @DitoQarcidze you want to wait until user press key and the `do this` if key is E or `do that` if other key pressed?

Comment: yeah do this if user pressed E and if he pressed anything other than that or nothing at all than do that,

Comment: @DitoQarcidze `or nothing at all` - so, there should be some timeout for waiting input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting your method as a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new Task(() => myMethod());
    t.Start();
}
```

When you test for `pressed` in your method, set it to `false`:

```
void myMethod()
{ 
    while (someBool)
    {
        //do something
        if (pressed)
        {
            pressed = false;
            //do this
        }
        else 
        //do that
    }
}
```

Of course, this can potentially cause a variety of multithreading errors, depending on what you actually do in `myMethod()`. I suggest that you look into [**thread synchronization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) before you start working with multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're attacking this problem isn't great as you shouldn't be blocking the GUI thread while you are waiting for user input. You should do whatever you are able to do, and then return immediately so that the GUI thread can process messages.

- On Form1_Load, run myMethod() where you can "do something" (initialisation) and then return immediately. Don't block here.
- On the KeyDown event, if E is pressed you can "do this". That part should be easy.
- I'm a little confused about when you want "do that" to run (i.e. the key is not pressed). Can you clarify when this case should happen?

Comment: As I mention in last comment myMethod() has while loop inside of it. "do that" should be executed if key was not pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Add timer component to your form and set it's interval to duration (in milliseconds) which you want to wait for user input:

```
bool someBool = true;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyPreview = true;
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
}
```

Start timer on form load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Add timer Tick event handler. This event will be raised if user did not pressed any key during specified waiting timeout (timer1.Interval). Also this event will be raised periodically instead of yours `while` loop:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (someBool)    
        //do that
    else
        timer1.Stop();       
}
```

On KeyDown event handler stop timer, then handle pressed key, and start timer to wait for next user input (or `do that` if there is no input):

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    if (!someBool)
        return;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E)
        // do this
    else
        // do that

    timer1.Start();
}
```